# How to divide characters after every dash in Oracle and create new columns based on extracted values?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g, substr

Here is an example for my data:

| ID |
| --- |
| 3-1-2 |
| 4-50-15 |

What I want is :

| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 50 | 15 |

What is the best way for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` (as it is faster than regular expressions):

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(ID, 1, INSTR(ID, '-', 1, 1) - 1) AS ID1,
       SUBSTR(
         ID,
         INSTR(ID, '-', 1, 1) + 1,
         INSTR(ID, '-', 1, 2) - INSTR(ID, '-', 1, 1) - 1
       ) AS ID2,
       SUBSTR(ID, INSTR(ID, '-', 1, 2) + 1) AS ID3
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID) AS
SELECT '3-1-2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '4-50-15' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 3 | 1 | 2 |
> | 4 | 50 | 15 |

---

If you did want to use (slower) regular expressions then:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(id, '[^-]+', 1, 1) AS id1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(id, '[^-]+', 1, 2) AS id2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(id, '[^-]+', 1, 3) AS id3
FROM   table_name;
```

*sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f793ce/5)*